# parse multiple dataframes from list of csv links, using date in link titles to concatenate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

sorry for the long title, i'm struggling a bit with the logic on this one

i have code which goes through the NOAA website and builds links from their degree days directory and subdirectories to build links to all of their text files (i'm sure this is not the best way so i won't be offended if someone tells me it could be better):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

topdir = 'https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/archives/Heating%20degree%20Days/weekly%20states/'
res = requests.get(topdir)
soup = bs(res.text,'html.parser')

toplinks = []
midlinks = []
csvlinks = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if re.search(r"^2\d{3}\/$", str(link.get('href'))):
        toplinks.append(link.get('href'))
        
for link in toplinks:
    midlink = topdir+str(link)
    midlinks.append(midlink)

for mlink in midlinks:
    mid = requests.get(mlink)
    msoup = bs(mid.text,'html.parser')
    for link in msoup.find_all('a'):
        if re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z]{3}%\d{4},%\d{6}\.txt$",str(link.get('href'))):
            csvlinks.append(mlink+str(link.get('href')))
```

the format for the links is effectively like so: `https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/archives/Heating%20degree%20Days/weekly%20states/2021/Mar%2020,%202021.txt`
and as you can see, the end of the link denotes month, year, and then day and year as a single number.

the csvs for each file look like:

```
            HEATING DEGREE DAY DATA WEEKLY SUMMARY
     POPULATION-WEIGHTED STATE,REGIONAL,AND NATIONAL AVERAGES
              CLIMATE PREDICTION CENTER-NCEP-NWS-NOAA
  
          LAST DATE OF DATA COLLECTION PERIOD IS MAR 20, 2021
          ACCUMULATIONS ARE FROM JUL  1, 2020 TO MAR 20, 2021
           -999 = NORMAL LESS THAN 100 OR RATIO INCALCULABLE
  
   STATE         WEEK  WEEK WEEK    CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM
                 TOTAL DEV  DEV     TOTAL DEV   DEV   DEV   DEV
                       FROM FROM          FROM  FROM  FROM  FROM
                       NORM L YR          NORM  L YR  NORM  L YR
                                                      PRCT  PRCT
  
 ALABAMA            39  -37   21    2147  -401   235   -16    12
 ALASKA            356   62   68    8372  -552   313    -6     4
 ARIZONA            83   22    4    1853   -43    70    -2     4
 ARKANSAS           67  -29  -19    3077   -70   282    -2    10
 CALIFORNIA        117   36   -6    1944  -126    52    -6     3
 COLORADO          222   18   34    5473  -427    15    -7     0
 ...               ...   ..   ..    ....   ...   ...    ..     .
 WEST VIRGINIA     135  -20    6    4157  -300   337    -7     9
 WISCONSIN         205  -23   -8    6092  -355   154    -6     3
 WYOMING           232    9   -2    6219  -406  -193    -6    -3
   REGION
 NEW ENGLAND       230   26   51    4903  -490    55    -9     1
 MIDDLE ATLANTIC   199   14   50    4418  -484   147   -10     3
 E N CENTRAL       181  -12    5    5082  -351   252    -6     5
 W N CENTRAL       170  -21  -23    5473  -286    86    -5     2
 SOUTH ATLANTIC     77   -6   30    2226  -272   213   -11    11
 E S CENTRAL        63  -37    2    2908  -266   269    -8    10
 W S CENTRAL        47  -11   21    2015   -89   240    -4    14
 MOUNTAIN          153   11    4    4040  -225     4    -5     0
 PACIFIC           127   33   -8    2406  -129    17    -5     1
 
 UNITED STATES     134    2   16    3518  -282   156    -7     5
              GAS HOME HEATING CUSTOMER WEIGHTED
   REGION
 NEW ENGLAND       224   26   52    4737  -468    72    -9     2
 MIDDLE ATLANTIC   198   14   50    4406  -476   150   -10     4
 E N CENTRAL       182  -11    5    5086  -352   251    -6     5
 W N CENTRAL       171  -21  -22    5483  -280    93    -5     2
 SOUTH ATLANTIC    102   -5   37    2866  -316   240   -10     9
 E S CENTRAL        65  -37    1    2944  -269   270    -8    10
 W S CENTRAL        49  -12   19    2104   -79   248    -4    13
 MOUNTAIN          165   10    7    4396  -260    -4    -6     0
 PACIFIC           123   34   -7    2221  -127    31    -5     1
```

with what I am looking to retrieve for each being the column headers and the first "region" section (I realistically only need the `WEEK TOTAL` column:

```
       REGION
     NEW ENGLAND       230   26   51    4903  -490    55    -9     1
     MIDDLE ATLANTIC   199   14   50    4418  -484   147   -10     3
     E N CENTRAL       181  -12    5    5082  -351   252    -6     5
     W N CENTRAL       170  -21  -23    5473  -286    86    -5     2
     SOUTH ATLANTIC     77   -6   30    2226  -272   213   -11    11
     E S CENTRAL        63  -37    2    2908  -266   269    -8    10
     W S CENTRAL        47  -11   21    2015   -89   240    -4    14
     MOUNTAIN          153   11    4    4040  -225     4    -5     0
     PACIFIC           127   33   -8    2406  -129    17    -5     1
```

I think what would make the most sense would be to have the date of the text file become the row identifier, with the regions as the column headers, and continually append the dataframe that way so that it could be sorted by date.

I am struggling with:

1. The logic to do this and
2. The pd.read_csv and determining the encoding

Comment: This is a nice data file, but it is not a csv file. I would not even try to use read_csv here, but directly use a custom parser

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for the input! I'm not very experienced with those, what would that be like?

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky that the table you want to extract is placed on the same line numbers in all `txt` files. This means that you can use `pd.read_csv`  with `skiprows=80` and `nrows=9` to extract exactly this table. Furthermore identifying multiple whitespaces as separator with a regex `sep=r"[ ]{2,}"` will get the table into a dataframe:

```
url = "https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/archives/Heating%20degree%20Days/weekly%20states/2021/Mar%2020,%202021.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(url, names=['REGION', 'GAS', 'HOME', 'HEATING', 'CUSTOMER', 'WEIGHTED', 'CUM DEV FROM L YR', 'CUM DEV FROM NORM PRCT', 'CUM DEV FROM L YR PRCT'], skiprows=80, nrows=9, sep=r"[ ]{2,}", engine='python')
```

output:

|  | REGION | GAS | HOME | HEATING | CUSTOMER | WEIGHTED | CUM DEV FROM L YR | CUM DEV FROM NORM PRCT | CUM DEV FROM L YR PRCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NEW ENGLAND | 322 | 48 | 100 | 3095 | 51 | 508 | 2 | 20 |
| 1 | MIDDLE ATLANTIC | 316 | 53 | 110 | 2864 | 13 | 570 | 0 | 25 |
| 2 | E N CENTRAL | 335 | 38 | 94 | 3153 | -71 | 520 | -2 | 20 |
| 3 | W N CENTRAL | 335 | 20 | 79 | 3285 | -175 | 517 | -5 | 19 |
| 4 | SOUTH ATLANTIC | 237 | 56 | 83 | 1914 | 68 | 301 | 4 | 19 |
| 5 | E S CENTRAL | 251 | 64 | 88 | 1950 | 66 | 278 | 4 | 17 |
| 6 | W S CENTRAL | 174 | 34 | 62 | 1315 | 18 | 153 | 1 | 13 |
| 7 | MOUNTAIN | 195 | -41 | -43 | 2750 | -245 | 130 | -8 | 5 |
| 8 | PACIFIC | 93 | -25 | -32 | 1182 | -206 | -29 | -15 | -2 |

You can now create a for loop to process the files:

```
for url in csvlinks:
    df = pd.read_csv(url, names=['REGION', 'GAS', 'HOME', 'HEATING', 'CUSTOMER', 'WEIGHTED', 'CUM DEV FROM L YR', 'CUM DEV FROM NORM PRCT', 'CUM DEV FROM L YR PRCT'], skiprows=80, nrows=9, sep=r"[ ]{2,}", engine='python')
    #do something with the df here, for example save it as csv: 
    pd.to_csv(url.split('/')[-1].replace('txt', 'csv'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module to parse the data (this example creates two dataframes from the first section and first region)

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/archives/Heating%20degree%20Days/weekly%20states/2021/Mar%2020,%202021.txt"
txt = requests.get(url).text

r_first_section = re.compile(r"(.*?)^\s*REGION", flags=re.S | re.M)
r_second_section = re.compile(r"^\s*REGION(.*?)^\s+$", flags=re.S | re.M)
r_row = re.compile(r"^ *[A-Z ]+?(?: +[\-\d]+){8} *$", flags=re.M)

first_section = r_first_section.search(txt).group(1)
second_section = r_second_section.search(txt).group(1)

data = []
for row in r_row.findall(first_section):
    data.append(row.strip().rsplit(maxsplit=8))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = []
for row in r_row.findall(second_section):
    data.append(row.strip().rsplit(maxsplit=8))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
                   0    1    2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0            ALABAMA   39  -37    21  2147  -401   235   -16    12
1             ALASKA  356   62    68  8372  -552   313    -6     4
2            ARIZONA   83   22     4  1853   -43    70    -2     4
3           ARKANSAS   67  -29   -19  3077   -70   282    -2    10
4         CALIFORNIA  117   36    -6  1944  -126    52    -6     3
5           COLORADO  222   18    34  5473  -427    15    -7     0
6        CONNECTICUT  210   21    54  4527  -481   105   -10     2
7           DELAWARE  160   11    54  3494  -534   172   -13     5
8   DISTRCT COLUMBIA  131    6    50  3140  -393   239   -11     8
9            FLORIDA    7   -9     7   477  -181   125   -28    36
10           GEORGIA   54  -25    25  2252  -320   192   -12     9
11            HAWAII    0    0     0     1     1     0  -999  -999
12             IDAHO  162  -17   -22  5289  -330  -139    -6    -3
13          ILLINOIS  177   -8     4  5084  -289   215    -5     4
14           INDIANA  161  -10     1  4715  -285   274    -6     6
15              IOWA  193   -7    -7  5929  -102   232    -2     4
16            KANSAS  133  -10   -12  4366   -91   197    -2     5
17          KENTUCKY  102  -30   -11  3707  -279   296    -7     9
18         LOUISIANA   31  -13    26  1621   -46   258    -3    19
19             MAINE  272   33    40  5838  -617  -115   -10    -2
20          MARYLAND  161   12    52  3748  -391   267    -9     8
21     MASSACHUSETTS  226   27    52  4742  -472    68    -9     1
22          MICHIGAN  203   -9     8  5322  -403   238    -7     5
23         MINNESOTA  208  -43   -40  6806  -558   -80    -8    -1
24       MISSISSIPPI   34  -34    17  2130  -206   245    -9    13
25          MISSOURI  135  -12   -10  4414  -122   199    -3     5
26           MONTANA  184  -35  -115  6205  -468  -143    -7    -2
27          NEBRASKA  173  -12   -23  5257  -312   122    -6     2
28            NEVADA  135   32    -6  3205     5   130     0     4
29     NEW HAMPSHIRE  252   25    45  5596  -612     2   -10     0
30        NEW JERSEY  187   17    55  4169  -382   197    -8     5
31        NEW MEXICO  147   13    24  3880  -188    56    -5     1
32          NEW YORK  213   19    54  4469  -570    84   -11     2
33    NORTH CAROLINA  104    1    47  2872  -230   291    -7    11
34      NORTH DAKOTA  202  -67  -101  7020  -884  -524   -11    -7
35              OHIO  166  -12    11  4589  -410   339    -8     8
36          OKLAHOMA   85  -18   -12  3453    89   362     3    12
37            OREGON  171   35    -4  3926   -70  -176    -2    -4
38      PENNSYLVANIA  186    5    41  4510  -416   209    -8     5
39      RHODE ISLAND  215   27    54  4406  -339    73    -7     2
40    SOUTH CAROLINA   72   -6    37  2313  -209   225    -8    11
41      SOUTH DAKOTA  202  -20   -32  5986  -572  -187    -9    -3
42         TENNESSEE   68  -44   -12  3323  -181   288    -5     9
43             TEXAS   41   -7    31  1725  -131   211    -7    14
44              UTAH  163  -14     5  5102  -288  -137    -5    -3
45           VERMONT  279   34    58  6181  -457    82    -7     1
46          VIRGINIA  143    8    52  3464  -377   269   -10     8
47        WASHINGTON  158   14   -23  4177  -171   -73    -4    -2
48     WEST VIRGINIA  135  -20     6  4157  -300   337    -7     9
49         WISCONSIN  205  -23    -8  6092  -355   154    -6     3
50           WYOMING  232    9    -2  6219  -406  -193    -6    -3
                 0    1    2    3     4     5    6    7   8
0      NEW ENGLAND  230   26   51  4903  -490   55   -9   1
1  MIDDLE ATLANTIC  199   14   50  4418  -484  147  -10   3
2      E N CENTRAL  181  -12    5  5082  -351  252   -6   5
3      W N CENTRAL  170  -21  -23  5473  -286   86   -5   2
4   SOUTH ATLANTIC   77   -6   30  2226  -272  213  -11  11
5      E S CENTRAL   63  -37    2  2908  -266  269   -8  10
6      W S CENTRAL   47  -11   21  2015   -89  240   -4  14
7         MOUNTAIN  153   11    4  4040  -225    4   -5   0
8          PACIFIC  127   33   -8  2406  -129   17   -5   1
```